# Add a custom admin action in Django when an object in another model is created

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I wanted to implement one functionality in my Django application such that a custom admin action is created whenever an object is created in some other model.

For e.g.
I have one model as Semester:

```
class Semester(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(_("Semester Name"), max_length=30, default=None, null=True, blank=True, help_text="Name of the semester")
    
      def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

and another model as UnregisteredStudent:

```
class UnregisteredStudent(models.Model):
      email = models.CharField(_("email"), max_length=30, default="")
      semester= models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.email)
```

In the UnregisteredStudent table I have emails filled up and am using custom admin actions to add semester field to each object in UnregisteredStudent table.

My custom admin action in UnregisteredStudent looks like:

```
@admin.action(description="Add Semester as Semester 1")
def semester1(self, request, queryset):
    semester = Semester.objects.get(name="Semester 1")
    for obj in queryset:
        obj.semester= semester
        obj.save(update_fields=["semester"])
```

Now as I have done this for semester 1, as and when new semester objects are created I would need new such admin actions like:

```
@admin.action(description="Add Semester as Semester 2")
def semester2(self, request, queryset):
    semester = Semester.objects.get(name="Semester 2")
    for obj in queryset:
        obj.semester= semester
        obj.save(update_fields=["semester"])
```

Right now I have to add custom admin actions manually in my `admin.py`, but I suppose this might not be the correct approach to the problem as in future when I have more objects adding custom admin action for each object might not be feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way is just to create a generator that generates admin actions, like:

```
def set_semester_action(semester_name):
    @admin.action(description=f'Add Semester as {semester_name}')
    def set_semester(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(semester=Semester.objects.get(name=semester_name))
    set_semester.__name__ = f'set_semester_{semester_name.replace(" ", "_")}'
    return set_semester
```

then we can construct the two (or more) actions:

```
@admin.register(student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = [
        set_semester_action('Semester 1'),
        set_semester_action('Semester 2'),
    ]
    # …
```

This will not only avoid duplicating code, but makes it less likely that for example the description is not equivalent to the `Semester` object we use, we thus make it less error-prone.

That being said, you might look at [**`django-mass-edit`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit) or similar packages, that allow to edit a queryset with a form, and thus allows selecting the semester yourself.

Comment: Though I will check on django-mass-edit, but while implementing the  former solution I got an error `(admin.E130) __name__ attributes of actions defined in about_Admin must be unique. Name 'set_semester' is not unique.`

Comment: @ishaanmittal: can you edit the `set_semester_action` by setting the name of the action before returning, see edit.